# error in zsh with curl?

Tags: zsh, curl

I want to run a curl command in zsh.

```
curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/<ZONE>" \ 
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \ 
-H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>"
```

but when run this I get

```
{"success":false,"errors":[{"code":9106,"message":"Missing X-Auth-Email header"},{"code":9107,"message":"Missing X-Auth-Key header"}],"messages":[],"result":null}curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
zsh: command not found: -H
zsh: command not found: -H
```

Besides the error response. Why do I get `zsh: command not found: -H` to me that means that the option `-H` is ignored.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each `\` in your code escapes a space character that follows. Escaped spaces behave like quoted spaces. Not only your code generates words that are spaces (and you don't want these words). The backslashes escape spaces, so they don't escape newline characters. In effect your code consists of three separate commands; two of them start with `-H` and make no sense. As if you run:

```sh
curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/<ZONE>" ' '
-H "Content-Type:application/json" ' '
-H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>"
```

Here the spaces are quoted, in your code they are escaped. The result is identical.

To continue a command in the next line you need to escape the newline character.

Remove the spaces after `\` characters. Each of your two backslashes should occur *immediately* before the respective newline character. Then the three lines will be interpreted as one command.

This is not specific to `zsh`.

Comment: ufff so somebody added a space after the backslash. I see